# IIS Subsite with different web.config, Is it possible?

Tags: asp.net, iis, publish

My IIS subsite take the web.config from the main site. How to avoid it?
I want my subsite just read its own web.config and works as independent site

This is how it looks in IIS:

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T615B.png)

Comment: You can't.

You can wrap some sections from the main site config in <location inheritInChildApplications="false"> elements; but some sections don't allow you to prevent inheritance.

In some cases, there will be a syntax to remove or clear the config that was inherited from a parent location. How you do that will depend on which config element is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, web.config contains the server configuration information related to each web application, there should be a web.config in the root folder of your web application.

If you want different web.config for subsite, you can place web.config file under your subsite of application.

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.web> 
    ...
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: True, but it also inherits the settings from the parent web.config. That is what I want to avoid.
I want it to just grab the web.config from your site

Comment: You can use the location tag with path value as `.` and inheritInChildApplications as `false` in the Web.Config file of root/parent application to fix this problem. you can refer to the code snippet in my answer.